# Call controller method from plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

In my `app/View/Elements/header.ctp` I have this line of code: `$menus = $this->requestAction('system/main_menu/');`

It is calling a method from `SystemController`.
However I created new Plugin and moved method from that controller into plugin controller.

How do I change this statement parameter to load method from plugin controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this syntax:

```
$menus = $this->requestAction('plugin_name/controller_name/method_name/');
```

and it worked well.

Comment: I would prefer to use the array based cake style URLs